# Looking for a counterexample for Ruelle's inequality on compact manifold

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let $M$ be a  compact differentiable manifold, and $f:M\to M$ be a $C^1$- smooth diffeomorphism.

If Assume that $\mu$ be a $f$-invariant probability measure on $M$. 
Then D.Ruelle proved that
$$
h_\mu(f)\le \int_M \sum_{i:\chi_i(f)>0} \chi_i(x)\dim E_i(x) d\mu(x)
$$
where $h_\mu(f)$ is measure theoretical entropy,  $\chi_i(x)$ are the Lyapounov exponents and $E_i(x)$ the corresponding Lyapunov spaces.

> I'm looking for an example on compact manifold that above Ruelle's inequality fails for it.

Comment: Which assumption of Ruelle's theorem do you want to drop?

Comment: I want to drop the regularity of $f$.

Comment: If there is no derivative, how do you DEFINE the characteristic exponents?

Comment: the point is, the measure of The singular set S contains those points $x$ where $f$ is either not defined, is discontinuous,not differentiable or else $D f(x)$ is non-invertible, and we have same inequality for the systems with non-flat singularities with two excess condition's, for more details look at this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601449.pdf

Comment: What do you mean regularity of f?